# .val() Returns Undefined Every Time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, undefined, onchange

So I have the following text boxes on my page:

[image]

When I enter a value in textbox1 I am able to get the value just fine by using the code below. However, as soon as I go on to enter a value for textbox2 then my variable 'value1' returns undefined all the time. What can I do to keep / save the value so that when I go on to enter the second value it does not return undefined for the first value? Any guidance / help is greatly appreciated it!

```
$(document).on('change', '.value1, .value2', function () {
    var current = $(this);
    var div = current.closest('.divClass');
    var value1 = div.find(".value1").val();
    var value2 = div.find(".value2").val();
  })
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="divClass">
        <label>TextBox1</label>
        @Html.TextBox("TextBox1", null, new { @class = "value1" })
        <br />
        <label>TextBox2</label>
        @Html.TextBox("TextBox2", null, new { @class = "value2" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML fragment so that it will be easier to reproduce this

Comment: Have you checked the existence of `.value1` and `.value2` as children of `.divClass`?

Comment: I have tried your code and the values are correctly logged: https://jsfiddle.net/fxm3L18n/

Comment: Okay I've added the html. Thank you! @SebastianKaczmarek

Comment: Yes I have @Mark

Comment: Yeah! They do log correctly however, for some reason when I go on to enter the value for the next textbox it returns undefined for value1. Thank you for checking out my code! @RomiHalasz

Comment: It does log correctly for me. Do you reset the values in some other code fragment that may be executed in between?